# DataGridView should only accept specific input format

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have some columns within a **datagridview** and I want that these columns only accept a specific input format.

```
Format: HH-mm-ss.fff, e.g. 11:37:55.378
```

Missing digits are not that important but it would be nice to fill them with zeros.

```
Example: 4:7:11.50 -> 04:07:11.500
```

If the user enters sth. completely different, e.g. "hello world" or "::::::" I want to clear that field.

I tried to work with the *CellFormatting*-event as written here http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx but without having success.

Comment: have you tried CellEndEdit event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve your goal.

1. If you want to make user exactly enter in the format you have mentioned then you have to use a custom `DataGridViewColumn` with masking capabilities. See this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26005/DataGridViewColumn-Hosting-MaskedTextBox) or [MaskedEditColumn article](http://www.vb-tips.com/MaskedEditColumn.aspx) for an idea.
2. If the validation is accpeted to be done later instead at user input level then you have to use the `CellValidating` event.

Sample Code:

```
void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    bool isValid = // Validate whether the entered data is in the required format.
    if (!isValid)
    {
        // clear the cell
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the CellValidating event. Within this context the following code might be helpful: mydataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "My user hint about the error!";  as well as e.FormattedValue.ToString() to access the value that needs to be checked